# IO Binary Writing Using Seekp; Moving Down Lines

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to create a binary file called Record.bin, and then write all of the information that the user inputs into that file. Right now it gets to the part where it reads in Student B[10], and it reads B[0] correctly, but all of the following elements of B[] are one step off. I can't figure out how to include a delimiter when the value is an integer.

After that there are some issues with my seeking, but I can't seem to understand why.

```
          #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
    char Name[20];
    char ANumber[9];
    int Age;
    float GPA;
};
int main(){
    Student A[10];
    Student B[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "Enter student's name" << endl;
        cin >> A[i].Name;
        cout << "Enter ANumber" << endl;
        cin >> A[i].ANumber;
        cout << "Enter Age" << endl;
        cin >> A[i].Age;
        cout << "Enter GPA" << endl;
        cin >> A[i].GPA;
    }
    fstream fout("Record.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        fout << A[i].Name << endl;
        fout << A[i].ANumber << endl;
        fout << A[i].Age << endl;
        fout << A[i].GPA << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
    fstream fin("Record.bin", ios::in);
    char tempe[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        fin.getline(B[i].Name, 25, '\n');
        fin.getline(B[i].ANumber, 25, '\n');
        fin.getline((char*)&B[i].Age, 25, '\n');
        fin.getline((char*)&B[i].GPA, 25, '\n');
    }
    fin.close();

    fin.open("Record.bin", ios::in);
    Student C;
    char*temp2 = "";

        fin.seekg(4 * sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
        fin.read((char*)&C.Name, sizeof(C.Name));
        fin.read((char*)&C.ANumber, sizeof(C.ANumber));
        fin.read((char*)&C.Age, sizeof(C.Age));
        fin.read((char*)&C.GPA, sizeof(C.GPA));
        fin.close();



     fin.open("Record.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    fin.seekp(4 * sizeof(Student), ios::end);
    fin.write(C.Name, sizeof(C.Name));
    fin.write(C.ANumber, sizeof(C.ANumber));
    fin << C.Age;
    fin << C.GPA;
    fin.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing binary files and formatted text output. If you have a binary file, why not use the unformatted binary `read` and `write` calls? If you use formatted output then writing an integer '1' is a different size than the integer '10'. But in unformatted binary both use 4 bytes (probably 4 bytes).

C++ iostreams have a 'g' (get) and 'p' (put) position. You need to use the correct seek functions.

If you are reading you need to use `seekg`. If you are about to write then you need `seekp`.

I am pretty sure that you are using the wrong seek function in at least one place.

Comment: Do the changes I just made reflect what you are talking about?

Comment: @TerikBrunson: Not exactly. You're using `getline` to read your strings. This probably works just because there's no `'\n'` in the file. But there could be!

The secret to a good binary format is fixed sizes. You want to be able to quickly seek to a record. In order to do that without reading all of the records in front of it you need to know it is exactly 300 bytes long (for example).

Comment: I know how big each one is. When I use seekg and seekp I am going to 4th element (4 *sizeof(Student). My problem is trying to read each element from the file and write it to B. I tried using fin.read, and it wouldn't store the information. Please help! :/

Comment: Or how do I use a delimiter if I'm using the read() function?

Comment: I tried to do it in the way you describe, but I still have problems, do you notice anything wrong?